# ggplot2: Add name of variable used for facet_grid

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggplot2, facet

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(vs+gear ~ cyl+am)
```

[image]

I would like to add the name of the 4 variables used for facet_grid on this graph. I suppose the best way to do so would be to add the name of the variables in the corners with a small arrow pointing to the row or column. I was thinking to use `annotation_custom` and `textGrob` for this purpose but failed to get anything printed on the graph.

Comment: Have you looked at `facet_grid(vs+gear ~ cyl+am, labeller = label_both)`?  Not quite the same, but gets the info on the graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(vs+gear ~ cyl+am,labeller = labeller(.rows = label_both, .cols = label_both))
```

You can also use syntax like so:

```
labeller = label_bquote("Gear"==.(gear))
```

Comment: Not quite what I was trying to do but that will work fine! Thank you